# Save only Bolded Text to a String Array in a Spanned String?

Tags: android, html, string, android-edittext, spanned

I have paragraph long stories that contain spanned strings with mostly regular text and a few bolded text (1 or 2 words) here and there. It's in an Edittext. I want to be able to search through that spanned string in the editText and save each bolded text to a string. I'm not sure how to do that though. Any suggestions?

Comment: bolded text maybe put in <strong> tab, inspect your text element and check that

Comment: @Tom How would I do this in Android Programming?

Comment: Your paragraph is displayed in html or element of XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `SpannableString`, you can use the `getSpans` method:

```
StyleSpan[] spans = ss.getSpans(0, ss.length(), StyleSpan.class);
List<String> boldedWords = new ArrayList<String>();
for(StyleSpan span : spans) {
    if(span.getStyle() & Typeface.BOLD) {
        int start = ss.getSpanStart(span);
        int end = ss.getSpanEnd(span);
        boldedWords.add(ss.subSequence(start, end).toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks great! I'll have to get back to you when I implement it.